# Horizontal lines in resume class?

Tags: cv, resume

I have a document as follows:

```
\begin{resume}

\section{Education}

% text here

\hrulefill

\section{Research Experience}

% text here

\hrulefill

\end{resume}
```

Essentially, I want to add a horizontal line between each section, but given that each section title is in a column on the left, and the content of that section is in a larger column to the right, the horizontal line just spans the second column when I want it to go along the first column of section titles too. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text inside the `resume` environment is shifted right of an amount equal to `\sectionwidth` in respect to the `\section`. So you need to go back of that amount of horizontal space.

For this purpose we define a new command `\fullhrulefill`:

```
\newcommand{\fullhrulefill}{%
  \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}\hrulefill%
  }
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{res} 

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for the example

\newcommand{\fullhrulefill}{%
  \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}\hrulefill%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

\section{Education}

\kant[1]

\fullhrulefill

\section{Research Experience}

\kant[1]

\fullhrulefill

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]